# Adding `$b ?? []` to array in PHP

Tags: php

When `$b` is not defined, I tried adding `$b ?? []` to `[]`. But an error occurred. However, executing `$b ?? []` by itself is no problem.

```
$a = [];
$result_1 = [] + $a ?? []; // success
$result_2 = [] + $b ?? []; // error
```

I think the following code would work, but I would rather not use it because I don't want to make my code overly complicated.

```
$_b = $b ?? [];
$result_2 = [] + $_b;
```

Comment: `$result_2 =  [] + ($b ?? []);`

Comment: [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php#language.operators.precedence)

Comment: @Mikey thank you ! I will read this article why I didn't do !!